# Is there a way to control USB 3 power with an Arduino?

Tags: power, usb

The scenario is the following: we have eight USB 3.0 devices connected to a PC. Sometimes these devices go haywire.  The only way to fix them is to physically disconnect and reconnect the cable. I'm looking for ways to use a board in the middle which can connect/reconnect the USB.

First I thought I'd make a board with 8 male and 8 female USB3 connectors with each of the VCC pins connected through a MOSFET. Is there a better or more recommended way?

The motherboard doesn't support cutting USB power.

Comment: Is the goal to do that automatically or manual? If manual a USB hub with switchable USB ports would be enough

Comment: The goal would be to do this automatically or via software, as the device itself wouldn't be easily accessible in the future

Comment: Then yes, a MOSFET circuit would be fitting. Products like a USB switcher is working the same way. Though this is an electronics question (doesn't have much to do with Arduino)